# Value Update notifications between ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Tab Control, with an "Exams" tab and a "Templates" tab. I want to share information between the two tabs.

My background is mostly in web with React and Redux, so my instinct is to have the shared information (of model type `Exam`) belong to the MainWindow, probably as a window resource.

My tech lead, who is much more experienced than me -- in all things, but also in C# though he's also new to WPF), assures me that this is not the way to do it in this setting, that the tabs' ViewModels should be sharing/passing the information.

So I've set up my basic UI with a text box in the Exams tab and a label to display the contents of the text box in the Templates tab.

```xml
<Page x:Class="Gui.Tabs.ExamsTab.ExamsHome" Title="ExamsTab">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="EXAMS TAB" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ExamString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding ExamString}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>

--------

<Page x:Class="Gui.Tabs.TemplatesTab.TemplatesHome" Title="TemplatesHome">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="TEMPLATES TAB"/>
            <Label Content="Text from Exams tab:"/>
            <Label BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Content="{Binding StringFromExamsTab}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And I've wired up the ViewModels best I can: (the code-behind and the viewmodels are in the same file for now)

```cs
namespace Gui.Tabs.ExamsTab {
    public partial class ExamsHome : Page {
        public ExamsHome() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
        public static readonly ExamsTabViewModel ViewModel = new ExamsTabViewModel();
    }

    public class ExamsTabViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private string _examString = "Default exam string";

        public string ExamString {
            get => _examString;
            set {
                _examString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

------

namespace Gui.Tabs.TemplatesTab {
    public partial class TemplatesHome : Page {
        public TemplatesHome() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        public static readonly TemplatesTabViewModel viewModel = new TemplatesTabViewModel();
    }

    public class TemplatesTabViewModel {
        public string StringFromExamsTab {
            // needs to be notified of value change!
            get => ExamsHome.ViewModel.ExamString;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Exams tab, the text-box and its corresponding label are synced up.
And, in the Templates tab, the red box says "Default exam string", but it doesn't change with the value in the text-box.

I've read that:

> The XAML binding engine listens for [the PropertyChangedEvent] for each bound property on classes that implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Which implies to me that as long as `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented in the Exams VM, the bindings in the Templates tab should be notified.

How can I make this work? Open to the possibility that I'm doing it entirely (or mostly) wrong.

Comment: First of all (while I'm thinking on the answer) I suggest to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) article. This article helped me a lot to understand MVVM after Winforms. Pay attention to *Relaying Command Logic* section (not connected with your question but extra useful).

Comment: Looking that no one answered here. I posted the solution earlier but it has been donvoted and I've deleted it. The idea was: 1) Implement INPC for `TemplatesTabViewModel`. 2) make `StringFromExamsTab` property regular with `OnPropertyChanged()` call. 3) Add `TemplatesHome.viewModel.StringFromExamsTab = value` into `set` of `ExamString`.